# resource not found error vs2010, mvc application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I got the below error when i set the properties of visual studio in WEB--->Specific Page
I set the specific page to /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
Requested URL: /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Can anybody assist me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the nature of how MVC works you cannot access a view directly. The whole point with MVC is that you should access a controller that then returns a view. So go to the controller action that returns the view you want to access.

If you want to control the first action accessed after F5 check this out: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-17-how-to-run-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx